# find out if an image contains another image in emgucv

Tags: c#, image, compare, emgucv

I am trying to find out with C# and emgucv if there is a smaller image inside a large image. but the smaller image has a transparent background (its sprite like).

`
using Mat result = new Mat();
CvInvoke.MatchTemplate(sourceImage, templateImage, result, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);
CvInvoke.Normalize(result, result, 0, 1, NormType.MinMax, DepthType.Cv32F);

```
double minVal = 0, maxVal = 0;
Point minLoc = Point.Empty, maxLoc = Point.Empty;
CvInvoke.MinMaxLoc(result, ref minVal, ref maxVal, ref minLoc, ref maxLoc);

matchScore = maxVal;
```

`

This is what I tried but it always returns a matchscore of 1.